# Laravel get Current URL parameters and append to new URL Request

Tags: php, laravel-4

In my Laravel app I have created a sidebar where I have links like

`/buy?state=NY or /buy?area=Queens` to let the user select a State or Area

I also have a form that lets Users Filter various things like rating, genre.
When i click on the Filter button, the url changes to something like

```
buy?min_year=1880&max_year=2019&min_rating=1&max_rating=10&genre=horror
```

it drops the `?state=NY or ?area=Queens` from the URL

I want to I change in the action to append the current URL parameters to the Filter string

I have tried

```
$url = Request::path();

if (isset($_GET["state"]) && !empty($_GET['state'])) {
$state = $_GET['state'];
$url = $url . "&state=". $state;

}
if (isset($_GET["council"]) && !empty($_GET['council'])) {
$council = $_GET['council'];
$url = $url . "&council=". $council;

}
if (isset($_GET["area"]) && !empty($_GET['area'])) {
$area = $_GET['area'];
$url = $url . "&area=". $area;
```

And then in my filter form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => $url, 'class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
```

but this results in the form returning this string.

```
/buystate=NY?min_year=1880&max_year=2019&min_rating=1&max_rating=10&genre=horror
```

when I want

```
/buy?state=NY&min_year=1880&max_year=2019&min_rating=1&max_rating=10&genre=horror
```

Comment: laravel routes are stored as Route::get('user/{name}', with a "/" separating the parameter to the variable, in my setup I am sending the parameters with "="

Comment: Why not using the features of the framework? Why you're sending params  with '='?

Comment: because /buy?state/NY&min_year/1880&max_year/2019&min_rating/1&max_rating/10&genre/horror  looks confusing?

Comment: Looks confusing to who? The browser? I suggest really reading about routing, wait I'll adapt my answer

Comment: I used hidden form fields to pass the parameters.. it was easier than re-doing my whole setup

Comment: Would you mind to vote my answrt, if it helped a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is for Laravel 4.x only!**

If I understand you well, this is what you need.

Laravel offers excellent Routing Features:

[laravel.com/docs/routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) (really worth reading!)

From the docs (adapted to your vars)

```
// Route::post(.... for forms)
Route::get('buy/{state}/{min_year}/{and_so_on}', function($state, $min_year, $and_so_on) {
   return array(
       'state' => $state,
       'min_year' => $min_year,
       'and_so_on' => $and_so_on
   );
});
```

The HTML part would then be something like

`<a href="buy/jersey/2012/and_so_on">Choose State</a>`

You may also group routings like so:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/state'), function(){
    Route::get('/{min_year}'), function() {...});
    Route::get('/{and_so_on}'), function() {...});
});
```

Comment: what if i need to handle URL like this:  buy/{state}?page=somepage ?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592826/basic-laravel-4-routing/25592890#25592890

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your problem, and I do agree that we're not supposed to be limited of the framework.

```
public static function get_full_route() {
    $split_url = explode('/', URL::full());
    $ret_url = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($split_url); $i++) if(strlen($split_url[$i]) > 0) $ret_url[] = $split_url[$i];
    return array("protocol" => $ret_url[0], "domain" => $ret_url[1], "route" => $ret_url[2]);
}
```

**Return**

```
// In my case
array(3) { 
   ["protocol"]=> string(5) "http:" 
   ["domain"]=> string(14) "localhost:8000" 
   ["route"]=> string(9) "login?a=1" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't help me so here is my version based on your example for reference.
Note this is with **Laravel 5.2** not Laravel 4 as indicated in the question. Note sure if it will work with Laravel 4.

First get the parameters form the current url.

```
$parameters = request( )->input( ); //return all GET parameters in an array.
```

You then add or edit what you want.

```
$parameters['state'] = $state; //this will set or override the 'state' value.
```

Push all the parameters to your desired route.

```
$url = route('search', $parameters);
```

Any parameters that are not matched in the route url are appended to the end of the url.

Happy dayz. :D