# Basic Laravel 4 Routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I would like to call a controller with parameters with this kind of configuration:

```
Route::pattern('d', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}', function($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
    // CALL A METHOD OF A CONTROLLER WITH PARAMETERS
});
```

Comment: Do you want `a` top be your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the controller method like this:

```
Route::get('/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}', 'AnyController@itsMethod');
```

And in the controller:

```
class AnyController extends BaseController {
    //...
    public function itsMethod($a, $b, $c, $d) {
        ///proceed your params
    }
    //...
}
```

**Laravel passes route-variables like `'/{a}/{b}/...` as parameter(s) to the called controller-method.**